# Infiltration & Neoplasia

Tags: meaning, word-choice, synonyms, science

I'm working on/reading a scientific article about the use and effects of Corticosteroid or Ketorolac on rabbit tendons and I got stuck at *infiltration* in the following excerpts:

> "Despite the increased adhesion formation noted grossly, minimal
>   differences in lymphocytic/plasmacytic **infiltration**, focal
>   histiocytic **infiltration** were noted between the (...) groups"
>
> "Tendon specimens were analyzed for evidence of necrosis,
>   lymphocytic/plasmacytic inflammatory **infiltration**, focal
>   histiocytic inflammation, and vascularity."

I found in medical dictionaries that *infiltration* is " the pathological diffusion or accumulation in a tissue or cells of substances not normal to it" but this definition is similar to *neoplasia*'s (according to *The Free Dicitionary*, "an abnormal new growth of tissue; abnormal proliferation of benign or malignant cells").

Does someone know if they can be synonyms?

Thank you.

Comment: From the two definitions you've quoted, it sure doesn't sound like they're synonymous; *infiltration* seems to carry a sense of a foreign agent, something the definition of *neoplasia* you quoted appears to lack.

Comment: I doubt that most authorities consider them to be synonymous,

Comment: This is very dark stuff, Tom.

Comment: Thank you so much. I didn't notice the difference. I read as if _not normal to it_ refers to _accumulation_, not _tissue/cells_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say that **inflammatory infiltration** refers to *diffuse* appearance of foreign cells, whereas **neoplasia** refers typically (but not always) to a  *mass* or *tumor*.

http://www.derm-hokudai.jp/shimizu-dermatology/pdf/02-04.pdf

Comment: I read as if _not normal to it_ refers to _accumulation_, not _tissue/cells_, so I didn't notice the difference. Big thanks for the pdf.

Answer (score 0):

*Neoplasia* and *infiltration* are definitely not synonyms.

Consider the VINDICATES mnemonic for [differential diagnosis:](http://www.rad.washington.edu/academics/academic-sections/msk/teaching-materials/online-musculoskeletal-radiology-book/general-principles)
**V**ascular, 
**I**nfectious, **N**eoplastic, **D**egenerative, 
**I**diopathic, 
**C**ongenital, 
**A**utoimmune,
**T**raumatic,
**E**ndocrine,
P**S**ychiatric

*Neoplasia* refers specifically to tumors.
From Merriam-Webster:
neo·pla·sia
\ˌnē-ə-ˈplā-zh(ē-)ə\
noun
1 :the formation of tumors
2 :a tumorous condition

Whereas *infiltration* can occur in many disease categories. Here's some examples from random articles:

**Neoplastic infiltration** of the sphenoid wing: a rare manifestation of metastatic colorectal cancer. Pinato DJ, et al. Asia Pac J Clin Oncol. 2011

Metrics of cellular and **vascular infiltration** of human acellular dermal matrix in ventral hernia repairs. Campbell KT, et al. Plast Reconstr Surg. 2012.

Rift Valley Fever Virus Encephalitis Is Associated with an Ineffective Systemic Immune Response and **Activated T Cell Infiltration** into the CNS in an Immunocompetent Mouse Model. Dodd KA, et al. PLoS Negl Trop Dis. 2014. (This one is infectious.)

COX inhibition enhances **inflammatory immune cell infiltration** in UV-irradiated human skin: implications for the treatment of sunburn.
Nakamura M, et al. Exp Dermatol. 2015.

Etc. etc. You can even have immune infiltration of a neoplasm:
Intratumoral CD8+ **Lymphocyte Infiltration** as a Prognostic Factor and Its Relationship With Cyclooxygenase 2 Expression and Microsatellite Instability in Endometrial **Cancer**.
Suemori T, et al. Int J Gynecol Cancer. 2015.